# Could not find the correct Provider<Cart> above this DetailsScreen Widget

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider

I get the following error:
Could not find the correct Provider above this ProductDetailsScreen Widget

This happens because you used a `BuildContext` that does not include the provider
of your choice. There are a few common scenarios:

My code:

```
    class Cart extends ChangeNotifier {
  final List<Product> _list = [];
  List<Product> get getItems {
    return _list;
  }

  icon: Badge(
                          showBadge: context.read<Cart>().getItems.isEmpty
                              ? false
                              : true,
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(2),
                          badgeColor: Colors.yellow,
                          badgeContent: Text(
                            context
                                .watch<Cart>()
                                .getItems
                                .length
                                .toString(),
                            style: const TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 16, fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
                          ),
                          child: const Icon(Icons.shopping_cart))),
```

any help appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to include your Cart provider in your runApp function in main. It should look something like this:

```
void main() {
    runApp(MultiProvider(
        providers: [
            Provider<Cart>(create: (context) => CartProvider()),
            // add all providers in a list
        ], 
        child: const MyApp(), 
    ));
}
```

It has to be initalized before you build the widget that needs it.

Comment: @Qube Great! Please confirm answer for others to see.